# Variable in the updated graph in SPARQL Update

Tags: rdf, sparql, updates, semantic-web

May I use a variable in order to define the graph(s) affected in a SPARQL update? For example, can i have:

```
INSERT 
  { GRAPH ?dest
    {
      ?person  foaf:name  ?name .
      ?person  foaf:mbox  ?email
    }
  }
WHERE
  { GRAPH  <http://example/people>
    {
      ?person  foaf:name  ?name .
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?dest` must be defined by the `WHERE` clause (else how does the system know where in `INSERT` the data?).

If you mean, all named graphs, then add `GRAPH ?dest {}` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: No, the WHERE clause defines the graph that the group graph pattern is evaluated not the graph that the triples are inserted. So to be more specific I meant if I am allowed to use a variable in order to specify  more than one graphs to insert the triples.

Comment: @Cheryl I think that what AndyS meant is that all variables in the `INSERT` must be bound by the `WHERE`.  Since the `WHERE` in this case doesn't bind `?dest`, the `INSERT` can't be performed.  You're absolutely right that the graph from which the triples come and the graph into which they're stored don't need to be the same, but you either need to use a definite IRI in the `INSERT`, or else bind `?dest` somehow in the `WHERE` so that it has a value for the `INSERT`.